# My new unit test is not behaving like a unit test

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

I'm writing some unit tests for a UWP app that I'm working on. I'm using VS 2019. I've noticed that VS 2019 has got a real big, annoying bug. I cannot do a Save All, without it hanging with no recovery, so I have to kill VS 2019 in order to stop it's being hung.

What makes matters worse, for me, is I am so used to doing a Save All that often forget that I shouldn't do that with VS 2019. (BTW, I'm experiencing the same problem at work using VS 2019 Enterprise Edition as I do at home using VS 2019 Community Edition. But I'm not working with the same project types.)

So, I created a new MSTest unit test project, added a reference to the project/class I wanted to test, renamed the new unit test class and created a method. Then I made the fatal mistake of trying to do a Save All, which caused it to fail. It really shouldn't, this unit test is pretty basic:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WeeklyTest()
{
    //assign
    var o = new SalaryConvUS();

    //act
    o.Hourly = 20.0M;
    var ret = o.Weekly;

    //assert
    Assert.AreEqual(800M, ret);
}
```

But, for some reason which I don't understand, VS 2019 doesn't seem to "see" this new unit test as a unit test. When I brought up the Test Explorer, it didn't recognize WeeklyTest as a unit test. I'm not sure what's going on. How can I fix it?

Comment: This doesn't look like a unit tests problem, but you computer/environment problem. You should first diagnose what is causing this Save All crashes. Do you have latest version of VS? Check this out: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/389759/vs-2017-1592-freezes-when-saving.html Also if that won't help, try to report this bug: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Reporting-Visual-Studio-crashes-and-performance-issues

Comment: @Peska, yes I have the very latest version of VS 2019. And thank you for pointing out Developer Community on the VisualStudio.com website. I wasn't aware of that being there.

Comment: @Rod Missing unit tests in Test Explorer is something I've encountered with NUnit based tests and discovered a solution (albeit not a permanent fix) https://robertwray.co.uk/blog/how-to-fix-nunit-tests-that-aren-t-showing-in-visual-studio-test-explorer - I'm dropping it as a comment rather than an answer for now as I don't know if the issue and resolution is the same with MSTest =)

Comment: Thank you, @Rob. Looking at your blog post I tried going to the VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions folder under my Temp folder. The VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions doesn't exist. Could that be the cause of my problem?

Comment: @Rod, if some tests are showing up, but not others, I think it's probably unlikely that it's the cause. I *think* that folder might be specific to *extensions* and MSTest is treated as 1st Party instead of 3rd Party. You could always try running up a test project that uses NUnit (the referenced packages in the blog post are exactly what's required) to see if that triggers creation of the folder / results in it still not being there as an investigative step =)

Comment: That's a good idea, @Rob. I've not used NUnit before, so this would be a good time to pick that up and try learning it.

Comment: @Rod, it's not all that different so if you do end up having a look at it you should get up to speed pretty quickly!